# Why does print() on tuple call __repr__ for elements of tuple and not __str__?

Tags: python

Why does print() on tuple call `__repr__` for each elements of tuple (with comma as seperator) and not `__str__`?

Comment: Would you really want to see the `\b` and `\n` and `\t` characters written out to your terminal each time you try to debug code using container objects like a tuple?

Comment: `print` calls `str` on whatever is passed to it. Tuples have the same definition for `__str__` and `__repr__` (one probably calls the other). You can see this with `str(('a',)) == repr(('a',))` or any other tuple. This happens to be based on the `__repr__` of the contained elements. So it has nothing to do with `print`, it's just how tuples are implemented.